# python 2 libraries got installed instead of python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, makefile, nose

I'm trying to build a python project with custom make file. This project has requirements.txt file which has many dependencies. All other dependencies except `nose` are installing properly (Python 3 modules) but only for nose it's installing python 2 modules. Below is the output while running testcases

```
Couldn't run '/home/user/user_Workspace/project-0.4-os11-lib64/project/lib/nose/core.py' as Python code: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (core.py, line 153)
make-4.3[1]: *** [//project/custommake:161: //project/test-factory-utils] Error 1
make-4.3[1]: Leaving directory '//project'
E       [core] custommake failed with exit code 2
make: *** [/home/user/user_Workspace/project-0.4-os11-lib64/custommake/custommake-bootstrap-setup.mak:275: bootstrap] Error 2
```

It used to work fine till few days back but suddenly started giving this issue recently. What might went wrong here ?

Comment: Check your [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) and make sure there are no Python 2 directories in it.

Comment: Hey @MarkRansom, Thanks for response. I've checked from where it's pulling seems in repository itself older version is present. I've checked nose package in pip https://pypi.org/project/nose/1.3.7/#files seems the tar file it has also has python 2 code. How can i find tar file for python 3 ?